# Fatal Error RecursiveIteratorIterator not found

Tags: php, class, namespaces, iterator, spl

As the title says, when I instantiate a class I get this message :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Envato\RecursiveIteratorIterator' not found in C:\Users\rgr\Apache\htdocs\Roland Groza [ 3.0 ]\class\envato\envato.php on line 359
```

You can view the class here : [Class](http://snippi.com/s/98c0bg8) ;

I'm instantiating from another file :

```
require("envato.php");
$test = new Envato\EnvatoAPIWrapper();
echo "User Vitals : ".$test->get_user_vitals("chaoscod3r")."<br>";
```

The class is wrapped with a namespace, so that might have something to do with it, but I wasn't sure since it's been a few years since I haven't coded PHP. Hopefully someone has an idea what is it that I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To access non-namespaced classes like the internal classes of PHP and SPL inside of a namespace you have to use the fully qualified class name like this:

```
new \RecursiveIteratorIterator();
```

or import it explicitly at the beginning:

```
use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;
```

and then use it normally like you do.

Comment: This applies for all of my methods or just for PHP core methods ?

Comment: It applies for all non-namespaced **classes**, user-defined or not. But not for functions, function names can be resolved dynamically as they are not subject to autoloading.

Answer (score 2):

Add a use statement at the top of your namespace...

use `\RecursiveIteratorIterator;`

If you don't then PHP expects `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to exist within your current namespace, rather than in the global namespace (indicated by the leading `\`)